# ClickListener error

Tags: android, intellij-idea, libgdx, clicklistener

In my game project I always get the error with the ClickListener:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 20791
Process: com.joelbrun.jetskirider.android, PID: 27784
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button.addListener(com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.EventListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.joelbrun.jetskirider.screens.MainMenu.show(MainMenu.java:40)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
        at com.joelbrun.jetskirider.JetskiRider.create(JetskiRider.java:11)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1511)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

Here is the code that causes the error:

```
startButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new Gamescreen());
        }
    });
```

Comment: You didn't show us what happens to the startButton object before that, so there's no way of knowing why it is null. How do you initialize that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that `startButton` is `null`, you have to initialize it before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

At addListener before, use findViewById to init Button, may be help you.